# CMake `test_big_endian` failed with `no suitable type found`

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
cmake version 3.19.4

CMakeFile.txt

```
    ...
    test_big_endian(WORDS_BIGENDIAN)
    ...
```

cmake output:

> -- Check if the system is big endian
> -- Searching 16 bit integer
> -- Looking for sys/types.h
> -- Looking for sys/types.h - not found
> -- Looking for stdint.h
> -- Looking for stdint.h - not found
> -- Looking for stddef.h
> -- Looking for stddef.h - not found
> -- Check size of unsigned short
> -- Check size of unsigned short - failed
> -- Check size of unsigned int
> -- Check size of unsigned int - failed
> -- Check size of unsigned long
> -- Check size of unsigned long - failed CMake Error at /usr/local/cmake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:51
> (message):   no suitable type found Call Stack (most recent call
> first):   contrib/xz/cmake/tuklib_integer.cmake:23 (test_big_endian)
> contrib/xz/CMakeLists.txt:126 (tuklib_integer)

CMakeError.log output:

> Determining if the include file sys/types.h exists failed with the following output:
> Change Dir: /data/clickhouse/clickhouse/ClickHouse/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/local/bin/ninja cmTC_73c6f && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_73c6f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_73c6f
> FAILED: cmTC_73c6f
> : && /usr/local/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always  -pipe -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt  -Wall  -Werror -w -fuse-ld=gold -rdynamic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-no-pie   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_73c6f.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o -o cmTC_73c6f   && :
> /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgcc_s
> /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgcc_s
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(syslog.o):function __vsyslog_chk: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(syslog.o):function __vsyslog_chk: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(syslog.o):function openlog: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(syslog.o):function closelog: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(syslog.o)(.eh_frame+0xd78b): error: undefined reference to '__gcc_personality_v0'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(backtrace.o):function backtrace_helper: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_GetIP'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(backtrace.o):function backtrace_helper: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_GetCFA'
> /lib/../lib64/libc.a(backtrace.o):function __backtrace: error: undefined reference to '_Unwind_Backtrace'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I found where the error occurred.
cmake-3.19/Modules/CheckIncludeFile.cmake:

```
  if(${VARIABLE})
      if(NOT CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
        message(CHECK_PASS "found")
      endif()
      set(${VARIABLE} 1 CACHE INTERNAL "Have include ${INCLUDE}")
      file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeOutput.log
        "Determining if the include file ${INCLUDE} "
        "exists passed with the following output:\n"
        "${OUTPUT}\n\n")
    else()
      if(NOT CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
        message(CHECK_FAIL "not found")
      endif()
      set(${VARIABLE} "" CACHE INTERNAL "Have include ${INCLUDE}")
      file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeError.log
        "Determining if the include file ${INCLUDE} "
        "exists failed with the following output:\n"
        "${OUTPUT}\n\n")
    endif()
```

What does the error mean? How to fix it?

---- new ----

`/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgcc_s` cause by gcc flag `-Wl,-no-pie`. Why `gcc_s` can not found?

Comment: I wouldn't concern too much that the test for big endian failed. (A good and portable implementation should word with big endian as well as little endian.) What would me seriously concern is why the test failed: `Looking for sys/types.h -- Looking for sys/types.h - not found -- Looking for stdint.h -- Looking for stdint.h - not found -- Looking for stddef.h -- Looking for stddef.h - not found`. About `sys/types.h`, I'm not completely sure but `stdint.h` and `stddef.h`? It seems that the C standard lib. headers cannot be found. (Even in C++, the C standard library is needed.)

Comment: The reason was the way `cmake` check if `sys/types.h` exsits was by executing command   `/usr/local/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always  -pipe -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt  -Wall  -Werror -w -fuse-ld=gold -rdynamic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-no-pie   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_735df.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o -o cmTC_735df`. But there was some error `/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgcc_s` when the command executed. I found this error occurred as the paramter `-Wl,-no-pie`. Without this, the command can execute successful.

Answer (score 1):

Btw in cmake 3.20 they introduced CMAKE_LANG_BYTE_ORDER.

Which is faster than using TestBigEndian: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_BYTE_ORDER.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_BYTE_ORDER

Answer (score 0):

The reason was version of `ld` too low (2.23). Updated to version (2.27), it works fine.